# Eclipse PyDev: Not working with many files inside project

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am having a data set inside my Eclipse PyDev project that represents about 8 million single .json files. Apparently Eclipse PyDev tries to do something with those files. I'm not sure what Eclipse is doing but it definitely is doing something.

How can I tell Eclipse to leave those files alone and not try to index or parse it because it slowly kills my CPU?

Answer (score 0):

Well, PyDev itself should do nothing with those files, but if there are other plugins (such as EGit) that could explain it...

Anyways, Eclipse itself will at the least index the resources by default.

A workaround here may be dealing with Resource filters: inside the PyDev Package explorer select the parent folder, Alt+Enter to see its properties (or right-click > properties) then select Resource > Resource Filters and add the filter to exclude those .json files.